# How to play as an octoling?

Tags: splatoon-2

I often play with players that play as an octoling, but I can't seem to find the option?

Do you need the Octo-expansion to play as an octoling or is the option hidden somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need Octo expansion DLC as far as I remember, and the [wiki](https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Octoling_(playable)) seems to confirm that:

> Octolings are only available after beating the Octo Expansion DLC.